# No sound card detected by alsa, (missing drivers?)

Tags: debian, drivers, audio, kali-linux, alsa

I'm on Kali Linux 2.0, on a laptop in dual boot with Windows 7 and I recently installed some module(chiptune) music players and after a reboot the next day the only sound card that I found in sound settings is Dummy Output.

So I tried purging pulseaudio and alsa and then installing them back again but it didn't work so here's a few commands that may give you more info :

```
$ lspci -v
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 6505
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7a14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 6505
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
    Memory at f7a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

I only kept the audio devices but I noticed that they don't have any kernel driver in use.

```
$ lsmod | grep intel
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
kvm_intel             151552  0 
kvm                   425984  1 kvm_intel
crc32c_intel           24576  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
aesni_intel           167936  0 
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
thermal_sys            32768  5 video,intel_powerclamp,thermal,processor,x86_pkg_temp_thermal
```

There doesn't seem to be any result for `lsmod | grep snd`

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:218: no soundcards found...
```

All of these makes me think that the drivers may be the cause but I never deleted them and I even reinstalled every packages that I removed and that could have been the cause of this.

I don't know if it's useful but this is the result of `modprobe` command for the intel driver:

```
$ sudo modinfo snd-hda-intel 
filename:       /lib/modules/4.0.0-kali1-amd64/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
description:    Intel HDA driver
license:        GPL
alias:          pci:v00001022d*sv*sd*bc04sc03i00*
alias:          pci:v00001002d*sv*sd*bc04sc03i00*
alias:          pci:v000015ADd00001977sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000017F3d00003010sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000013F6d00005011sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001102d00000009sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001102d00000012sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001102d00000010sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00006549d00002200sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00006549d00001200sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc04sc03i00*
alias:          pci:v000010B9d00005461sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001039d00007502sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001106d00009140sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001106d00009170sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001106d00003288sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AAB0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AAA8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AAA0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00009902sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA98sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA90sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA88sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA80sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA68sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA60sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA58sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA50sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA48sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA40sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA38sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA30sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA28sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA18sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA10sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA08sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000AA00sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000970Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000960Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00007919sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000793Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d0000780Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d00004383sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001002d0000437Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d*sv*sd*bc04sc03i00*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003A6Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003A3Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000293Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000293Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000284Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000269Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000027D8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002668sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002284sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000F04sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000080Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000811Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003B56sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000160Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D0Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000C0Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000A0Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00009D70sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A170sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00009CA0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00009C21sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00009C20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00008D21sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00008D20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00008CA0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00008C20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001E20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001D20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001C20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        snd-hda-controller,snd-hda-codec,snd-pcm,snd
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.0.0-kali1-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           index:Index value for Intel HD audio interface. (array of int)
parm:           id:ID string for Intel HD audio interface. (array of charp)
parm:           enable:Enable Intel HD audio interface. (array of bool)
parm:           model:Use the given board model. (array of charp)
parm:           position_fix:DMA pointer read method.(-1 = system default, 0 = auto, 1 = LPIB, 2 = POSBUF, 3 = VIACOMBO, 4 = COMBO). (array of int)
parm:           bdl_pos_adj:BDL position adjustment offset. (array of int)
parm:           probe_mask:Bitmask to probe codecs (default = -1). (array of int)
parm:           probe_only:Only probing and no codec initialization. (array of int)
parm:           jackpoll_ms:Ms between polling for jack events (default = 0, using unsol events only) (array of int)
parm:           single_cmd:Use single command to communicate with codecs (for debugging only). (bool)
parm:           enable_msi:Enable Message Signaled Interrupt (MSI) (bint)
parm:           patch:Patch file for Intel HD audio interface. (array of charp)
parm:           beep_mode:Select HDA Beep registration mode (0=off, 1=on) (default=1). (array of bool)
parm:           power_save:Automatic power-saving timeout (in second, 0 = disable). (xint)
parm:           power_save_controller:Reset controller in power save mode. (bool)
parm:           align_buffer_size:Force buffer and period sizes to be multiple of 128 bytes. (bint)
parm:           snoop:Enable/disable snooping (bint)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I had no answer I ended up recompiling the whole kernel and now my sound is working again.
Now the result for `lspci -v` is:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 6505
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f7a14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 6505
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f7a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

This means the problem was kernel drivers.
But I still don't know how to fix this without recompiling the whole kernel.